# How to preselect a value in dropdown from angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a dropdown as follows.

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="UpdateTeacher.TeacherId" name="TeacherName" value={{UpdateTeacher.TeacherId}} required #TeacherName="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor="let TeacherDetail of this.userService.TeacherDetails" value="{{TeacherDetail.TeacherId}}">
            {{TeacherDetail.TeacherName}} </option>
 </select>
```

Now this.userService.TeacherDetails is an array of Teacher objects which i am iterating.I have a value already set in UpdateTeacher.TeacherId as 2 When displaying the drop down 2 option must be pre selected. How to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

value should be written as an input  `[value]="something"`

i.e

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="UpdateTeacher.TeacherId" name="TeacherName" value={{UpdateTeacher.TeacherId}} required #TeacherName="ngModel">
      <option *ngFor="let TeacherDetail of this.userService.TeacherDetails" 
         [value]="TeacherDetail.TeacherId">
        {{TeacherDetail.TeacherName}}
      </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Not Working @koech

Comment: does UpdateTeacher.TeacherId have a default value? If it doesn't it won't work.

Comment: yes it has. I have found the solution .I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="UpdateTeacher.TeacherId" name="TeacherName" value={{UpdateTeacher.TeacherName}} required
      #TeacherName="ngModel">
      <option *ngFor="let TeacherDetail of this.userService.TeacherDetails" selected="{{UpdateTeacher.TeacherId == TeacherDetail.TeacherId}}"
        value="{{TeacherDetail.TeacherId}}">
        {{TeacherDetail.TeacherName}} </option>
    </select>
```